# How to place a div over a google map

Tags: css, google-maps

I need to place a div over a google map, the map has to be responsive, so #map-menu can't be on absolute position

this is the code:

```
<div id="map-container">
   <div id="map"></div>
   <div id="map-menu">Text</div>
</div>

#map-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position:relative;
}
```

thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I added

```
#map-menu {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: `#map-menu` must be `absolute` or `fixed`. Your map can still be responsive this way.

Comment: fixed position worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Use position absolute and z-index

```
<div id='map' >
</div>

<div id='search_location' >
......
</div>
```

and for css

```
#search_location{   
   position: absolute; 
   top:6px;     
   right: 235px;    
   width:680px; 
   height:30px;
   z-index: 2000; 
               ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
add class "inner" to divs
```

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.inner').wrap( "<div id="map-container"></div>");
 });
```